# How to run a Runnable thread in Android at defined intervals?

Tags: android, multithreading

I developed an application to display some text at defined intervals in the Android emulator screen. I am using the `Handler` class. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");               
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

When I run this application the text is displayed only once. Why?

Comment: I can never remember how to do a runnable, so i always visit your post on how to do it :))

Comment: lambdas are the way to go now most of the time ;)

Answer (score 576, accepted):

The simple fix to your example is :

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Or we can use normal thread for example (with original Runner) :

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                handler.post(this);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

You may consider your runnable object just as a command that can be sent to the message queue for execution, and handler as just a helper object used to send that command.

More details are here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Alex, i have one small doubt.Now the thread is running perfectly and displaying the text continously, if i want to stop this means what i have to do?Please help me.

Comment: You may define boolean variable _stop, and set it 'true' when you want to stop. And change 'while(true)' into 'while(!_stop)', or if the first sample used, just change to 'if(!_stop) handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)'.

Comment: If you want to be sure that Handler will be attached to the main thread, you should initialize it like this: handler =  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: @alex2k8 Shouldn't it be handler.post(r) instead of handler.post(this) in the second snippet? Moreover, if you want to use the solution with Thread, you also have to remove handler.postDelayed(this, 1000) from the Runnable r, as the delay is already executed inside of run() method of the Thread object.

Comment: @alex2k8 - Hi bro! Please tell me how to stop the 2nd snippet `Thread` manually while running?

Answer (score 55):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do something...              
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: If you want to be sure that Handler will be attached to the main thread, you should initialize it like this: new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: Isn't this solution equivalent to the original post?  It would only run the Runnable once after 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 40):

I think can improve first solution of Alex2k8 for update correct each second

**1.Original code:**

```
public void run() {
    tv.append("Hello World");
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
```

**2.Analysis**

- In above cost, assume `tv.append("Hello Word")` cost **T** milliseconds, after display **500** times delayed time is **500*T** milliseconds
- It will increase delayed when run long time

**3. Solution**

To avoid that Just change order of postDelayed(), to avoid delayed:

```
public void run() {
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    tv.append("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: -1 you are assuming the task you perform in the run() is a costs a constant amount each run, if this were operation on dynamic data (which typically it is) then you would end up with more than one run() occuring at once. This is why postDelayed typically is placed at the end.

Comment: @Jay Unfortunately you are wrong. A Handler is associated with a single Thread (and a Looper which is the run method of that Thread) + a MessageQueue. Each time you post a Message you enqueue it and the next time the looper checks the queue it executes the run method of the Runnable you posted. Since that is all happens in just one Thread you can't have more than 1 executed at the same time. Also doing the postDelayed first will get you closer to a 1000ms per execution because internally it uses current time + 1000 as execution time. If you put code before the post you add additional delay.

Comment: @zapl thanks for the tip about the handler, I assumed it would be executing multiple runnables and hence, multiple threads. Internally though, a condition such as if ((currenttime - lastruntime)>1000) will work fine when run durations are less than or equal to 1000ms, however, when this is exceeded, surely the timer is going to be occuring at non linear intervals dependant entirely on execution time of the run method (hence my point on unpredictable computational expense)

Comment: If you want a fixed period, w/out conflict, measure the start time before doing work, and adjust your delay accordingly.  You will still see a little latency if the cpu is busy, but it can allow you a stricter period, and to detect if the system is overloaded (perhaps to signal low priority stuff to back off).

Answer (score 31):

**For repeating task you can use**

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, runAfterADelayForFirstTime, repeaingTimeInterval);
```

call it like

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        },500,1000);
```

> The above code will run first time after **half second(500)** and repeat itself after each **second(1000)**

Where

**task** being the method to be executed

**after** the time to initial execution

(**interval** the time for repeating the execution)

**Secondly**

And you can also use **CountDownTimer** if you want to execute a Task number of times.

```
    new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) { //40000 milli seconds is total time, 1000 milli seconds is time interval

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      }
      public void onFinish() {
     }
    }.start();

//Above codes run 40 times after each second
```

And you can also do it with runnable. create a runnable method like

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

        }
    };
```

And call it in both these ways

```
new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 500 );//where 500 is delayMillis  // to work on mainThread
```

**OR**

```
new Thread(runnable).start();//to work in Background
```

Comment: For option #3 how can i pause/resume and also stop permanently?

Comment: create an instance of Handler like Handler handler = new Handler() and remove it like handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Answer (score 25):

I believe for this typical case, i.e. to run something with a fixed interval, `Timer` is more appropriate. Here is a simple example:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
@Override
public void run() {
    // If you want to modify a view in your Activity
    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        public void run(){
            tv.append("Hello World");
        });
    }
}, 1000, 1000); // initial delay 1 second, interval 1 second
```

Using `Timer` has few advantages:

- Initial delay and the interval can be easily specified in the `schedule` function arguments
- The timer can be stopped by simply calling `myTimer.cancel()`
- If you want to have only one thread running, remember to call `myTimer.cancel()` **before** scheduling a new one (if myTimer is not null)

Comment: I don't beleive that a timer is more appropriate as it does not consider the android life cycle. When you pause and resume, there is no guarentee that the timer will run correctly. I would argue that a runnable is the better choice.

Comment: Does that mean when an app is put in the background a Handler will be paused? and when it regains focus it will continue (more or less) as if nothing had happened?

Answer (score 18):

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");                       
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }
}; 
handler.post(r);
```

Comment: This should give an error. In your second line you're calling variable `r` which is defined yet.

Comment: If you want to be sure that Handler will be attached to the main thread, you should initialize it like this: handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: just repetitious answer !

Answer (score 6):

#### Kotlin

```
private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val handler = Handler()
    runnable = Runnable {
        // do your work
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
}
```

#### Java

```
Runnable runnable;
Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do your work
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How do we execute other functions inside Runnable?

Comment: why handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)  has written twice?

Comment: one handler is for first starting runnable and then it once run, it will initiate another one. @meekash55

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly the documentation of Handler.post() method:

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

So examples provided by @alex2k8, even though are working correctly, are not the same.
In case, where `Handler.post()` is used, **no new threads are created**. You just post `Runnable` to the thread with `Handler` to be executed by [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).
After that, EDT only executes `Runnable.run()`, nothing else.

Remember:
`Runnable != Thread`.

Comment: True that.

Don't create a new thread every time, ever.  The whole point of Handler and other execution pools is to have one or two threads pull tasks off a queue, to avoid thread creation and GC.

If you have a really leaky app, the extra GC might help cover up OutOfMemory situations, but the better solution in both cases is to avoid creating more work than you need to.

Comment: So better way to do this is by using the normal thread based on alex2k8's answer?

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin with Coroutines

In Kotlin, using coroutines you can do the following:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { // Main, because UI is changed
    ticker(delayMillis = 1000, initialDelayMillis = 1000).consumeEach {
        tv.append("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Try it out [here](https://pl.kotl.in/EYb_7GfJK)!

Comment: How to cancel this CoroutineScope any button click event

Answer (score 1):

An interesting example is you can continuously see a counter/stop-watch running in separate thread. Also showing GPS-Location. While main activity User Interface Thread is already there.

Excerpt:

```
try {    
    cnt++; scnt++;
    now=System.currentTimeMillis();
    r=rand.nextInt(6); r++;    
    loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(best);    

    if(loc!=null) { 
        lat=loc.getLatitude();
        lng=loc.getLongitude(); 
    }    

    Thread.sleep(100); 
    handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {   
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error="+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

To look at code see here:

[Thread example displaying GPS Location and Current Time runnable alongside main-activity's User Interface Thread](https://letsmakeandroidapp.wordpress.com/2017/08/25/step-7-learning-thread-with-roll-dice-static-counter-and-gps-location/)

Comment: Hint: if you want to make your answer useful - learn how to format input here. That *preview* window exists for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

now in Kotlin you can run threads this way:

```
class SimpleRunnable: Runnable {
    public override fun run() {
        println("${Thread.currentThread()} has run.")
    }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val thread = SimpleThread()
    thread.start() // Will output: Thread[Thread-0,5,main] has run.
    val runnable = SimpleRunnable()
    val thread1 = Thread(runnable)
    thread1.start() // Will output: Thread[Thread-1,5,main] has run
}
```