# Asynch thread stopping main UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog

Can anyone tell me why the following dialog box does not show until the *asynchronous* thread has finished.  I cannot figure this one out.  This is running in the main UI thread.  Not sure why a new thread would affect the flow of the main UI thread

```
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

                dialog.show();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         while(imageLoader.isProcessing()) {}
                         doSomething();   
                     }
                 }).run();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the `start()` method of the anonymous Thread, not the `run()` method.

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> public void start(): Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.

Answer (score 2):

call the start method

i reccomend to use use AsyncTask
see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  , it has proper thread handling mechanism

[see this example as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect threads to follow the flow of your code. I suggest to use AsyncTask and for showing the dialog you can show the dialog in onPreExecute() and remove it in onPostExecute()

or may be you like to try runOnUiThread()