# How to run some code for 20 seconds in android

Tags: android, seconds

I want to run some code for 20 seconds precisely. It is similar to a loop but instead of having a variable I have time (in seconds).

I should have a time condition like this:

```
do

{ variable++ }

while (sec < 20)
```

How it is possible to do this in Android??

My application should run this 20 sec code after the user presses a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class in Android on a runnable and then use the postDelayed() method. That way you will be able to update the UI during that 20 seconds on the progress of the thread. A good example of this is [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android). Your code might look something like this ...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        //Do thing after 20 sec        
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 20000);
```