# How do I call a specific PreferenceFragment from a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity with several fragments:

**R.xml.preferences:** (shortened for better readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:fragment="fragments.Fragment1" android:id="@+id/fragment1" [...] />
    <header android:fragment="fragments.Fragment2" android:id="@+id/fragment2" [...] />
    [...]
</preference-headers>
```

**SettingsActivity**:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
    }
}
```

This will show a list entry with `fragments.Fragment1`, `fragments.Fragment2`, ... if `SettingsActivity` is started.

But now I want to pass a Bundle such that a specific PreferenceFragment is opened when starting the activity:

so I added this to **SettingsActivity**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("shortcut")) {
        // directly jump to fragments.Fragment1
    }
}
```

I tried to load the fragment via `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)`, but this returns `null`. But even if I had the correct instance, I would not know how to invoke it. Also, calling `loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences_fragment1, target);` does not work - This will throw a RuntimeException "*XML document must start with  tag; foundPreferenceScreen at Binary XML file*". I have no ideas left and also a search on SO and Google did not return any relevant results.

So my question is: Is it possible to directly load a PreferenceFragment (e.g. fragments.Fragment1) from the Activitiy's onCreate method? If so, how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT

> public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT
>
> Added in API level 11 When starting this activity, the invoking Intent
>   can contain this extra string to specify which fragment should be
>   initially displayed.
>
> Constant Value: ":android:show_fragment"

```
intent = new Intent( this, SettingsActivity.class );
intent.putExtra( PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, Fragment1.class.getName() );
intent.putExtra( PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true );
```

Comment: Really cool they supported this.  Thanks for sharing.  It worked well for me also.

Comment: It works. I am also trying to pass request action to that activity by `putExtra` but `Bundle savedInstanceState` is always null. Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code in your **PreferenceActivity** and **PreferenceFragment** in **onCreate**

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.**YOUR PREFERENCE FRAGMENT XML**);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use [PreferenceActivity.switchToHeader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#switchToHeader(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)).
When starting the PreferenceActivity, the header/overview of all settings pages is loaded first and then the fragment. When finishing the fragment, you will return to the overview.

**MyPreferenceActivity:**

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> headers) {

    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, headers);

    int headerId = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getIntExtra("header", 0) : 0;
    if (headerId > 0) {
        getIntent().removeExtra("header");
        switchToHeader(findHeaderById(headerId));
    }
}

private Header findHeaderById(long id) {

    if (headers != null)
        for (Header header : headers)
            if (header.id == id) return header;

    return null;
}
```

This shows how to call the PreferenceActivity together with the fragment in your **MainActivity**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("header", R.id.header1);
intent.putExtra("key", "pref1");
startActivity(intent);
```

If necessary, you can open the respective preference right away in **PreferenceFragment1**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_1);  

    String key = getActivity().getIntent() != null ? getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("key") : null;

    if (key != null) {
         getActivity().getIntent().removeExtra(key);
         openPreference(key);
    }
}

private void openPreference(String key) {

    PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
    ListAdapter listAdapter = preferenceScreen.getRootAdapter();

    for (int position = 0; position < listAdapter.getCount(); position++) {

        Preference preference = (Preference) listAdapter.getItem(position);

        if (preference.equals(findPreference(key))) {
            preferenceScreen.onItemClick(null, null, position, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**preference_headers.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<preference-headers
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <header android:id="@+id/headers1"
        android:fragment="de.almisoft.PreferenceFragment1"
        android:title="Title1"
        android:summary="Summary1">
    </header>

    <header android:id="@+id/headers2"
        android:fragment="de.almisoft.PreferenceFragment2"
        android:title="Title2"
        android:summary="Summary2">
    </header>

</preference-headers>
```

**preferences_1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
        android:key="pref1"
        android:title="title"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```