# Installing a support library for PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, preferencefragment, preference-v7

I'm new to Android Studio and a total beginner at Android programming in general. I looked and looked and I couldn't find the right thing to do.

All I want is to install a library to use **PreferenceFragmentCompat** or any class that replaces **android.app.PreferenceFragment** so my app can work in API 11 and lower.

Can anyone please give me some details such as which library should I use and how to install it in my AS project.

**Edit:** So I started developing this app using `android.support.v4` and `android.support.v7` libraries to handle the Fragments so I can run it on API 11 and lower.

this is my **MainActivity.java.**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Fragment mainFragment = null;

        switch(position) {
            case 0: // home fragment
                mainFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1: // favorites list
                mainFragment = new FaveFragment();
                break;
            case 2: // rate app
                /* visit app TODO put application package id in the link */
                Intent visitStore = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                visitStore.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
                startActivity(visitStore);
                break;
            case 3: // settings
                mainFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                break;
            case 4: // about
                mainFragment = new AboutFragment();
                break;

        }

        if(position != 2) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, mainFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.section_titles);
        if (number >= 1) {
            mTitle = stringArray[number - 1];
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Now this is my **SettingsFragment.java:**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

The real problem I encounter here is with this line: `mainFragment = new SettingsFragment();` in the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)` method in **MainActivity.java**.

It returns an error saying:

> Error:(70, 32) error: incompatible types: SettingsFragment cannot be
>   converted to Fragment

How can I fix this and still be able to use my app on API 11 and lower?

Comment: The question is a bit too board. You can check this example: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html but you should try to start with some codes and the ask for help when you're stuck with it. I don't see any "PreferenceFragmentCompact" anywhere

Comment: you're right, editing it

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405773/how-to-use-preferencefragment there it says how to open a PreferenceFragment/Activity.

Comment: I don't know how is that going to help me?

Comment: You are trying to open the PreferenceFragment as a regular Fragment and that is not going to work (because is not a "Fragment"). You need a header for the PreferenceActivity and that one will open the PreferenceFragment.

Comment: "You'll need a header listing for each preference screen (fragment)." read the answer there... is the solution.

Comment: I'll fix that but the issue I want fixed is that android.preference.PreferenceFragment only runs with API 11 and higher and I want my app to work with APIs lower than that..

Comment: Well... PreferenceFragment is just a SharedPreference "view". You can use my library https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver it's a easy version of SharedPreference and it works from Android 2.1 You can save the data there, get the values and ask if exist or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89113/discussion-between-anaslmt-and-mariano-zorrilla).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After adding `com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.1` to your build.gradle file, simply change the line

For AndroidX : `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0`

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
```

to

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
```

The error is caused by `PreferenceFragment`, which extends `android.app.Fragment`, not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` which you need, as you are using support library class.

Comment: I don't have the library that contains the PreferenceFragmentCompact installed, what is that library called and how can I install it on AS?

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.0.1'` to your gradle

Comment: This worked, thanks. I needed to install the library.

Comment: don't forget to update to the new version. It has some impotent bug fix: compile "com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0"

Comment: a noob question I guess: where do you see the info in which library it is? I mean, how do you know to add the particular compile statement? Because when I read through the PreferenceFragmentCompat documentation it says nothing about adding this compile statement, I have to go to Support Library in documentation and basically keep up to date if anything changes so I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to know what to compile without too much digging around?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?utm_campaign=ADP-protip-827&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=plus&linkId=16598683#v7-preference

Comment: [Check here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-preference) for latest version of the support preference library.

Comment: Can I use this library for compile SDK 22?

Answer (score 34):

For anyone using `androidx`, add this to your dependencies

```
dependencies {
    
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:{your_version}'
    // example: implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Preference releases can be found here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference