# How to make progressbar (loading animation) in my project?

Tags: android, sms, progress-bar, loading, handle

I make project like this : [Fetch Messages from Inbox](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-fetch-inbox-sms/)

Part of code :

```
while  (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    String address = cursor.getString(1);
    String body = cursor.getString(3);

    // Loading too long
    System.out.println("======> Mobile number => "+address);
    System.out.println("=====> SMS Text => "+body);
    sms.add("Address=> "+address+"\n SMS => "+body);   
}
return sms;
```

But, there are too many message and need long time to show. While loding i want to show the animation `(progressbar)`

Thanks you...

Comment: I suggest you to do this with `AsynTask` That would very helpful one for you. Do this code in your `doInBackground()` method. Have a look at this [Example](http://www.androidsnippets.com/grab-a-url-source-with-progressdialog-and-asynctask)

Comment: Im very confused using AsynTask.. and example code hard from me. can you edit that code and use AsynTask? thanks 4 help me. Im newbie..

Comment: Did you every try anyone of the answers below

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would use AsyncTask for such a thing on Android..

***Intro:*** By default all code you write not using threads,services,etc.. will execute in    `UI thread`.. That means that if you do some expensive work there, user interface will be blocked (not responsive). Good practise is to move such a expensive task to separate thread, otherwise you app will show `ANR` dialog and be closed.

***How:*** One of the best approach for your case is use of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).. Basically in `onPreExecute()` you show progress dialog or "long task in progress" animation. In `doInBackground(Params... params)` you put code of expensive operation. In case u need to update progress bar you do it from `onProgressUpdate(Progress... values)`. When expensive task finishes it will provide results to `onPostExecute(Result result)` method. From this one you can update UI again and close previously displayed progress dialog.

Hope it helped. Cheers.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Asyntask`, put that code in `doInBackground` , start `processbar` in `onPreExecute()` , dimiss in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

Implement Runnable in your project. Run this code

```
while  (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
String address = cursor.getString(1);
String body = cursor.getString(3);

// Loading too long
System.out.println("======> Mobile number => "+address);
System.out.println("=====> SMS Text => "+body);
sms.add("Address=> "+address+"\n SMS => "+body);   
}
//return sms;// Make a global variable which can hold values here...
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

in

```
run()
```

method. Now start the thread like this:

```
Thread fetchSmsThread = new Thread(this);
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,title,message);
fetchSmsThread.start();
```

Handler Code:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler()
 {

  //////Catch Message Here.. and Dismiss dialog...
  ///Note You have to declare progress dialog as global so that you can access it here...

 }
```

For further help about runnable follow this:

[How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

If you dont want to use Runnable then use Android AsynClass, follow:

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Progressbar in main.xml with an id (yourProgressBarId in the example below):

```
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    final ListView lViewSMS = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSMS);  

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.yourProgressBarId);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {

                ArrayList sms =fetchInbox();
                if(sms!=null) 
                lViewSMS.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sms);  
                         lViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);  
                         progressBar.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
                }
          });
    }   
}.start();

}
```

Comment: i got error line this :
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new
ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item
_1, sms);

can u fix that? thanks..

Comment: ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(NameOfYourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sms);  Appreciate if you mark it as answered if it helps you :)