# Making a Simple Recurring Text Update Continue Indefinitely

Tags: android, date, textview, recurrence

I have a very function function inside the activity that takes a static date in the past, formats it to a relative string using `DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString` (so it becomes something like "3 minutes ago" and sets it to a `TextView`. However, I want this `TextView` to keep updated so long as the activity stays open.

How do I make a continuous task that will either run continuously (infinite loop) or run within short intervals - like every second. How to accomplish this without getting into background services and such?

Comment: Use AsyncTask, and do the conversion in `doInBackground` and publish it to `onProgressUpdate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using AsyncTask

```
private class BackgroundCoversionTask extends AsyncTask< String, String, Void >{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( String... params ) {

        while( !isCancelled() ){
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                break;
            }

            //DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString( MainActivity.this, time, minResolution, transitionResolution, flags )
            // Do something right here
            publishProgress( Long.toString( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate( String... values ) {
        super.onProgressUpdate( values );

        mTextView.setText( values[0] );
    }

}
```

Then if you want to cancel the task, call `cancel()`

Answer (score 0):

Just run it on a separate thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                //Do your date update here
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

See: [How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

With threads please make sure that when the app is paused or resumed you appropriately pause or resume your thread. Also it is a good idea to end them yourself at the end of the activity lifecycle for the sake of handling any data you might want