# set textview color programaically for the item under section header Listview

Tags: android

I have implemented a Section header Listview where i inflate a layout which have three textviews in it as item.i have referred this example [here](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) to achieve it.

My code is

```
adapter.addSection(monthitems2[l], new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.phone_row, 
                new String[] {"Title", "Caption","val1" }, new int[] { R.id.tvContact, R.id.tvMobile,R.id.tvMail }));
```

I have a condition where i need to change text color of ID "R.id.tvContact".I havent defined the textview anywhere in thelayout.i have just referred it as simpleadapter parameter.How to change the textview color the default is white.Any suggestions answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference tutorial, you have

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);  
adapter.addSection("Array test", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "First item", "Item two" }));  
adapter.addSection("Security", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex,   
        new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));  

ListView list = new ListView(this);  
list.setAdapter(adapter);  
this.setContentView(list);
```

Get a handle to your TextView, then set its color from that handle. You need to Post the
commands to the message queue, in a runnable, b/c at this point in the code the ListView hasn't yet rendered the TextView's that the adapter points to (that will happen sometime after OnCreate exits).

```
list.Post(() => 
{
    TextView tv = list.FindViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvContact);

    tv.SetTextColor(Color.Red);
});
```

I don't think you need to qualify FindViewById with list. b/c you set the content view with

```
this.setContentView(list);
```

(above code in C# for MonoDroid, easily convertable to Java).

Posting runnables in Java/Android: [How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Posting in runnables puts the code in the message queue, a key, undocumented construct in Android. Anytime you get a null reference from an activity when modifying Views, try this as a first step.

Comment: Oh, post it in a runnalbe (see above for edits). I'll add a link for posting runnables in java. You need to do this b/c the view is not yet rendered.

Comment: Do you set R.layout.phone_row with SetContentView(R.layout.phone_row) ? If so, you don't need to qualify FindViewById with a reference (its implicit b/c FindViewById is a member of the Activity class your coding in).

Comment: Nope my oncreate method have been set to another layout.this is an adapter layout where an item of listview can be displayed.

Comment: i gave it this way but same error comes up..

RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.phone_row);
  TextView tv =  (TextView) lay.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);

  tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: According to the referenced tutorial, its in the list. So do list.FindViewById (your going to have to do it in a runnable b/c the adapter wont render the TextViews until after OnCreate exits).  Where ListView list = new ListView(); list.setAdapter(adapter);