# Function similar to fork() in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, fork

I am coding for an app in Android and am facing the following problem.

I have to override an inbuilt function `Fragment getItem(int position)` to return the Bitmap of an image, but as the image is quite large it takes lots of time to load. So, the UI is a bit slow in responding.
To resolve this i think it can be resolved like in the following code. It basically returns a blank image immediately and when the real image is loaded it returns the proper image.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        pid = fork();  //NOT POSSIBLE / ERROR
        if (!pid)
            return  (code for empty image);
        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment(files[position].getAbsolutePath(), width, height);
    }
```

But, I do not know of a function similar to `fork()` in Java.
Can you please help me out with this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you would use the <kbd>Thread</kbd> class for that. However, if you are developing for Android, you might consider using <kbd>AsyncTask</kbd> and refer the official android developer training for

[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forking new processes, in Java you open Threads for cases like this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an AsynTask and when implementing his functions do something like

```
public class imageLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

 protected preExecute(){
  //load the blank image
  //this function is executed on the UI thread
 }

 protected doInBackground(){
  //load the real one
  //that one is not executed on the UI thread
 }

 protected postExecute(){
  //set the new image 
  //this one is executed on the UI thread
 }
}
```