# Java synchronized thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Not sure whether this D class thread is correct. Is there a race condition, is `i` supposed to be in a synchronized block when accessed? What if D is an outer class, and the A instance was passed to a D constructor?

```
class A
{
    int i;
    void f() {
        i++;
        D d = new D();
        d.start();
    }
    class D extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            int g = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated, as the others seem to have you covered, but it is considered bad practice to extend `Thread`.

Comment: Google devs do it all the time in android sample code!

Comment: Here's the [better approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android). This way you cannot find yourself accidentally overriding things, nor are you carrying a lot of extra memory baggage that you don't need.

Comment: As is, no issue at all. You increment `i` before you start the thread and no thread modifies `i` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe as long as you only invoke `f` once. There is a happens-before relationship between a thread A that mutates data and a thread B that's started from thread A (the HB-relationship being at `Thread.start`). Since nobody mutates data after `D` is started, this is safe.

Some ways to break the thread safety:

- mutate `i` again, including by invoking `foo` again
- read `i` from a thread other than `D` or the one that invoked `foo`

The reason that you can't mutate `i` again, even from the thread that invoked `foo`, is that this mutation would have happened after `d.start()`, and would therefore have no HB edge against that second mutation.

The reason you can't read `i` from any arbitrary thread is that this thread wouldn't have a well-defined view of the `i++` mutation.

It can get a tad more subtle than that, but at a high level, there you go.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a race condition?

Possibly if you call `f` from more than one thread as you would be accessing a shared variable (`i`) without proper synchronization.

Note however that **starting a thread creates a happens-before relationship**.

So `g` will be equal to the value of `i` right before the thread was started (i.e. the value of `i` when `d.start()` is called) or any subsequent values if `i` has been modified by another thread in the meantime (with no guarantee that such modifications are actually seen).

Answer (score 1):

If `f()` will be called from one and the same thread there will be no problem because `start()` guarantees that `i` is visible from `run()` and `run()` does not change `i`. Otherwise you need `AtomicInteger` or `synchronized`. Note that simply `volatile i` will not help, some `i++` may be lost.