# How to display image based on weather from drawable

Tags: android, eclipse, weather

i would like to display an image based on the weather.
The image that I'm getting from is from drawable.

For example :
if the code = 30, it will display rainy day icon

I'm retrieving it from

```
   <yweather:condition  text="Light Rain with Thunder"  code="4"  temp="25"  date="Thu, 18 Jul 2013 7:58 am SGT" />
```

Here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView weather;
 ImageView image;

 class MyWeather{


  String conditiontext;
  String conditiondate;

  String numberOfForecast;
  String forecast;

  public String toString(){

   return "\n- " 
           + "Weather:" + image + "\n"

    + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n"
    + conditiondate +"\n"

    + "\n"
    + "number of forecast: " + numberOfForecast + "\n"
    + forecast;

  } 
 }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

     @Override
     public void run() {
      weather.setText(weatherResult.toString());
     }});

   }});
        myThread.start();
    }

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

     MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

        //<yweather:condition.../>
     Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
     if(conditionNode.getTextContent().equals("11")){
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
     }
     else {

     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
     }
     myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
       .getNamedItem("text")
       .getNodeValue()
       .toString();
     myWeather.conditiondate = conditionNode.getAttributes()
       .getNamedItem("date")
       .getNodeValue()
       .toString();

     //Added to get elements of <yweather:forecast.../>
     NodeList forecastList = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast");

     myWeather.forecast = "";
     if(forecastList.getLength() > 0){
      myWeather.numberOfForecast = String.valueOf(forecastList.getLength());
      for(int i = 0; i < forecastList.getLength(); i++){
       Node forecastNode = forecastList.item(i);
       myWeather.forecast +=
         forecastNode
          .getAttributes()
          .getNamedItem("date")
          .getNodeValue()
          .toString() + " " +
         forecastNode
          .getAttributes()
          .getNamedItem("text")
          .getNodeValue()
          .toString() +
         " High: " + forecastNode
             .getAttributes()
             .getNamedItem("high")
             .getNodeValue()
             .toString() +
         " Low: " + forecastNode
             .getAttributes()
             .getNamedItem("low")
             .getNodeValue()
             .toString() + "\n";
      }
     }else{
      myWeather.numberOfForecast = "No forecast";
     }

     return myWeather; 
    }

    private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){

     Document dest = null;
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder parser;

     try {
      parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes())); 
     } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return dest; 
    }

    private String QueryYahooWeather(){

     String qResult = "";
     String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c";

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

     try {
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

      if (httpEntity != null){
       InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
       Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
       BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

       String stringReadLine = null;

       while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
       }

       qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
      } 
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return qResult; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `Image` the `ImageView` that needs to be updated as per the weather? What variable holds the value on which the weather depends upon?

Comment: hi, yes , it is needed to be  updated as per weather.

 Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
     myWeather.conditiontext1="";
     myWeather.conditiontext1 = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code").getNodeValue().toString();
if(myWeather.conditiontext1 == "4"){
      //Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
     // Image.setImageDrawable(myDrawable) ;
      Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
           }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not working?

I made the project myself, and if you do it like this it will work. :)

*The R.id and drawables are not the same, you need to change those to make it work*

```
 TextView weather;
 ImageView forecast;
 private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 class MyWeather{


  String conditiontext;
  String conditiondate;

  String numberOfForecast;
  String forecast;

  public String forecastToString(){

   return "\n- " 
           + "Weather: " +"you wanted to have something here, I just dont understand what. " + "\n"

    + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n"
    + conditiondate +"\n"

    + "\n"
    + "number of forecast: " + numberOfForecast + "\n"
    + forecast;

  } 
 }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        forecast = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

     @Override
     public void run() {
      weather.setText(weatherResult.forecastToString());
     }});

   }});
        myThread.start();
    }

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

     MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

        //<yweather:condition.../>
     Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);


     String weatherCode = conditionNode.getAttributes()
           .getNamedItem("code")
           .getNodeValue()
           .toString();

     if(weatherCode.equals("28")){

         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
                // Views

                 forecast.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        });

     }
     ...
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: Maybe the toString() function is messing things up because Strings have it's own toString() function.
Might want to change the name of the function to forecastToString() or something.

Comment: Hi,
I've just change the code.
The above is my latest code.

THE GUI didn't display the image , however it written something " android.widget.ImageView@4055c7f8"

Comment: why not use: Image.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
Might be the problem.

Comment: there is an error at this part
setImageDrawable

it have been  underlines

Comment: Make sure the logo file is in the drawable folder. Then clean and build your project. 
I have to go to bed, I'll check up on you tomorrow. :)
And note, try to not use same names as android/java uses. Like toString() and probably Image.

Comment: Hi,
all right, goodnight

hmm, my image is all along inside drawable folder

Comment: Hi,
If I would like to put a else in it, is it like this?


  if(weatherCode.equals("15")){

          mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
                 // Views

                  forecast.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
             }
         });

      }
      else {
       
        forecast.setImageResource(R.drawable.old);
      }

Comment: The code you gave works. However, when I put the else, it fail to do so..
just wondering do I get the else correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I found some problem in your code there is two image view

```
 Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Problem - : name of the image missing

```
 ImageView foreImage = new ImageView(this);
 foreImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

//Why are you using dynamic imageview

You should use Handler Thread for display image.

Comment: Google bro. Google. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android