# Wait until Spinner is refreshed

Tags: android, spinner

I have a kind of form with 3 Spinners. The content of 2 Spinners (minorSpinner) depends on the selection of the first one (mainSpinner). To be more precise, I set the content of those 2 minorSpinner in the mainSpinner's onItemSelected listener.

The form can be saved and load back again.

The problem is:
When I am trying to load the form, first I set the mainSpinner and then minerSpinners.

Like:

```
mainSpinner.setSelection(value);
minorSpinner1.setSelection(value1);
minorSpinner2.setSelection(value2);
```

Unfortunatelly the minorSpinners are not ready in time. Maybe because their values are set in the UI Thread?

Question:

how to wait until they are ready?

What I tried:

```
runOnUIThread(){
mainSpinner.setSelection(value);
minorSpinner1.setSelection(value1);
minorSpinner2.setSelection(value2);
}
```

but ti does not work:(

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> how to wait until they are ready?

So my first idea is to register `OnItemSelectedListener()` for all Spinners.

Then create two boolean variables for example isSpinnerOneSelected, isSpinnerTwoSelected and when you'll select item from Spinner, assign variable to true.

Then create some `Thread` (with Handler) that will control your states. If both variables are assigned to true, just make action with third Spinner.

If you don't know how to use Handler, look at:

- [How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Comment: hm, so Handler thread should monitor if the mainSpinenr changes? I don't see why it would help

Comment: Anyway, I just realized that I am already doint this all stuff in the UI Thread so runOnUIThread is unnecessary :)

Comment: @Remarkable you need to use thread if you want real time control or listener.