# Android - Google Places API - REQUEST_DENIED App Only

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

So I'm in the beginning stages of my app and don't have a server backend yet.  So for now I'm parsing the JSON from Google Places inside the App (in general I would need to do that on the server side, right?)

Since I don't have a server I generated a "Key for Server Applications" using the IP 0.0.0.0/0

My second question is, **sometimes** I get a "REQUEST_DENIED" when I run the following command: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=REF_NUM&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY` on the phone but of-course it works when I run it on curl.

Am i doing something wrong? what doesn't it work all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be making too many requests per second?  Try putting a one second delay between requests and see if that helps.  Ultimately, the delay can probably be shorter, but starting here could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: yeah it seems to be that exactly where i run `JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(new GetPlaces().execute(sb.toString()).get()).getJSONObject("result");` sb being the command that pulls details data and it's running in a for loop. what's the best way to delay that?

Comment: any idea as to what i should be doing?

Comment: Take a look at [Handler.postDelayed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).  How many requests could you be sending at one time?  I regularly send up to 20 details requests back to back and haven't had a problem.

Comment: same, i run it for every item returned by nearbysearch which i'm assuming is defaulted to 20.

Comment: you know i did use Handler.postDelayed using the example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android) where i substituted `tv.append("Hello World");` with my command `JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(new GetPlaces().execute(sb.toString()).get()).getJSONObject("result")` but it's failing.  is that the right approach?

Comment: any help will be greatly appreciated @pushbit.  would love to just close this question

Comment: looks like it was just too many requests but still not too sure.  i'll still check your answer :) thanks for the help