# Return back to the activity after calling another app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity which I use to call another app using implicit intent. How do I get back to the original activity after running the called app for some amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

use StartActivityForResult(intent);

Comment: Niphin, Thanks for your reply. But This another app is more like a game where I am just calling it using an implicit intent. How do I get the result back from the game since I cannot modify the game?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you won't be able to terminate the other app but here's something you can do

You can create a `Service` that contains a [postDelayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android) `Handler` which starts the desired `Activity` you want.