# how to Non-stop animation until the exit of activity

Tags: java, android

i want made animation, Until the outside of activity, animation has not stoped and And continues until the activity is running animations

my animation code :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="30000" >

</rotate>
```

please send to me current code

Comment: Write animation in code and run in new thread, or you whant close you program finaly ?

Comment: @MaxVitruk : can you send me thread code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android

Comment: Is that that what you need ? Or you need  to keep rotation during app close ?

Comment: @MaxVitruk, yes I want running animation when close activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE).

```
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

Comment: tnx dear friend, but this is not work. after android:duration="10000" animation is stoped. I want non-stop and repeat Until the exit Activity.

Comment: tnx Dear FAHIM <3 , I added this code in animation xml file : android:repeatCount="infinite" and this work. tnx your help <3