# How can I delay onClick action

Tags: java, android, multithreading, random, delay

I am trying to do something in java app (android) and I need something to delay/wait for an amount of seconds for a loop. How can I do delay android function? I have tried to use Thread.sleep(), TimeUnit.sleep, but it is only going to do irresponsible program for some seconds. I want to do some onClick actionlistener which updating for some seconds.
e.g: if I clicked to button -> Text is changed to random(int) and it's should be done per second.

> random ... waiting for a second ... random ... waiting for a second
>   ... random ... and so many times

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int random = r.nextInt(100) - 10;
    String rand = Integer.toString(random);
    textView3.setText(rand);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing the random number generation on a parallel thread?

Comment: @RobertoLombardini Thanks for your mention. I'll try to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Handler` with `postDelayed`, example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Log.d("Log:", "Hello!");
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        int random = r.nextInt(100) - 10;
        String rand = Integer.toString(random);
        textView3.setText(rand);            
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
}
```

look at this question: [How to run a Runnable thread in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with android app programming

But if you want a random number is printed to the text for every one second... how about using Timer instead of Delay?

I don't know how the code in Android works but the Logic should be like this:

Button Pressed:

```
Timer.Start(1000)
```

For every timer tick:

```
int numberVariable = random(1,10)
textVariable = numberVariable.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler with a timer, like this:

```
public Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Handler class to delay the loop for whatever amount of time you want. It goes like this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your function goes here.
        }
    }, 5000); /your time in micro seconds.
```

**Hope it helps.**

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a lot of ways to do this.

**From:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072338/2801237

The benefit of this is that you don't need to deal with a handler, and you can easily randomize the '5' seconds input (plus it is clear that it is 5 seconds), not 5000ms. (more below)

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker = 
          Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

void someMethod() {
  ⋮
  Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      /* Do something… */
    }
  };
  worker.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ⋮
}
```

---

and another big benefit of this approach is that you can expand this quickly/easily to use threadpool.

```
  private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker =
         Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4); //thread pool of 4 threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void randomStart() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000*1);
            try {
                Random r = new Random();
                int random = r.nextInt(100) - 10;
                String rand = Integer.toString(random);
                textView3.setText(rand);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1*1000);
}
```