# TextView setText not working inside ScheduledExecutorService runOnUiThread

Tags: android, textview, scheduledexecutorservice, android-runonuithread

Code :

```
private void startTimer() {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int count = 60;
                    time.setText(count - 1 + "");
                    count--;
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0 , 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I want to update text in TextView for every 1 second, but this seems to work only for the first time and later text is not updated.

Anyone know what's the issue ??

Comment: `I want to update text in TextView for every 1 second,` Why not using Handler.postDelayed ?

Comment: I want it to update every 1sec for 60 seconds, this seems apt

Comment: check example http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: you can check my answer :)

Comment: sry guys my bad, I gave int count = 60; inside run so it always shows 59

Comment: @Logic No problem .Move ahead .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int count = 60;
private void startTimer() {
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             if(count > 0){
               time.setText(count - 1 + "");
               count--;
             }
          }
       });
     }
   }, 0 , 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Above code is working perfectly can you please tell the reason to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Read **[How to run a Runnable thread in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android)**

You can use **Handler**

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is
>   associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When
>   you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of
>   the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver
>   messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they
>   come out of the message queue.

You need to use `handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()` method .

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached .

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       // Add your code Here

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // You can change your time
      }
    }, 900);
```

Comment: I have searched for a very long time, and this is the only working solution I could find for my problem.

Comment: @iTadreik Glad to hear!