# creating delay in execution of program

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a delay in my code in such a way that one portion should be executed after 5 seconds and other portion after 10 seconds. I have tried TRY CAtcH threading but don't know where is the issue.. here Is my code kindly have a look at it.. Thanks in adavnce....

```
 // This portion to be executed after 5 seconds 

              val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(unit.getText()));
              val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(unit2.getText()));
              result = val1 + val2;

              val = Integer.toString(result);
             int len = val.length();

              if (len == 1) {

                  num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 1)));

                  unitanswer1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));
                  unitanswer2.setText(Integer.toString(0));
                  unitanswer2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

              } else {
                  num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 1)));
                  unitanswer1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));

                  num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 2)));
                  unitanswer2.setText(Integer.toString(num2));
              }
```

// This portion to be executed after 10 seconds

```
             val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tens.getText()));
             val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ten2.getText()));
             val3=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(unitanswer2.getText()));

             result = val1 + val2 + val3;

            val = Integer.toString(result);
             len = val.length();

            if (len == 1) {

                num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 1)));

               tenanswer1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));
                tenanswer2.setText(Integer.toString(0));
                tenanswer2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            else {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 1)));
               tenanswer1.setText(Integer.toString(num1));

                num2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(val.toString().charAt(len - 2)));
                tenanswer2.setText(Integer.toString(num2));

                //Animation's work to be done here.....
                //remaining possibilites of addition....
            }
            }
```

Comment: Use two [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This portion to be executed after 5 seconds 
             ...
        }
    },5*1000);
```

and this:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //This portion to be executed after 10 seconds
            ... 
        }
    },10*1000);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

A generic function would be:

```
 /**
 * This function runs some actions after some delay
 *
 * @param delayInMilliSeconds the time delay in ms
 * @param runnable            the action to perform after the delay
 * @return the Handler object, with which one can cancel this action.
 */
public static Handler runDelayedAction(int delayInMilliSeconds, Runnable runnable) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayInMilliSeconds);
    return handler;
}
```

Usage:

```
Handler h = runDelayedAction(5000, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //DoSthYouLike();
    }
});

h.cancel(); //You can even cancel this at your own discretion.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aysnctask, I hope it helps.You can do as follow :

```
    SplashAsyncTask = new SplashAsyncTask();
    asyncTask.execute(SPLASH_TIME);
```

And SplashAsynctask would look like

```
     public class SplashAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
                SystemClock.sleep(integers[0]);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if(!isCancelled()){
                "do whatever task you have to do"
        }
    }
```

Define SPLASH_TIME as:

`private static final int SPLASH_TIME=3000;`