# How add timeout for AsyncTask in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

l am a beginner in Kotlin. 
I am using AsyncTask to execute JSON data from an API. I want to add a  timeout after a certain period of time in case a user has a very slow or spotty data connection, then show the user an alert dialog, saying, "Sorry you don't have proper internet connectivity" with a button when clicked closes the app.

This is my `AsyncTask` code:

```
 inner class Arr : AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){



        }

        //        for build connection
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String{

            var text : String
            val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

            try {
                connection.connect()
                text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use{reader -> reader.readText()} }


            } finally{

                connection.disconnect()

            }
            return text
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

            super.onPostExecute(result)
            handleJson(result)


        }

        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {


        }
```

Comment: Easy way to do such this thing is by using `Runnable` and `Handler` where you can **disconnect your connection** when delayed runnable executes.

Comment: the problem is , l dont know how to write that code

Comment: add a timeout to your network call

Comment: @ManojPerumarath l dont know how to write that code , l am beginner

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android-at-defined-intervals

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this thing. Two examples are as below :

1. Adding timeout using `HttpURLConnection`:

   ```
   try {
       connection.connectTimeout = 5000 // We all timeout here
       connection.connect()
       text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use{reader -> reader.readText()} }
   } finally{
       connection.disconnect()
   }
   ```
2. Disconnecting manually using `Handler` & `Runnable` *(We can achieve same thing using CountDownTimer or any other stuff too)* :

   ```
   try {
       connection.connect()
       text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use{reader -> reader.readText()} }
       // We all timeout here using Handler
       Handler().postDelayed(
           {
               connection.disconnect() // We disconnect manually
           },
           5000 // Timeout value
       )
   } finally{
       connection.disconnect()
   }
   ```

**Edit for O.P.:**

Use below class for making **API call** and showing alert to user *if connection is timed out*.

```
//We pass context to Activity/Fragment to display alert dialog
inner class TestApiCall(private val context: Context?) : AsyncTask<String, String, String?>() {

    //        for build connection
    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String? {
        var text: String? = null
        val connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

        try {
            connection.connect()
            text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use { reader -> reader.readText() } }
            handleTimeout { timedOut ->
                if (timedOut) {
                    text = null
                    connection.disconnect()
                    print("Timeout Executed")
                }
            }
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
        return text
    }

    private fun handleTimeout(delay: Long = 5000, timeout: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            timeout(true)
        }, delay)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        if (result != null) {
            //Handle result here
            print("Result --> $result")
        } else {
            //Result is null meaning it can be timed out
            context?.let { ctx ->
                val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                alertDialog.setTitle("Some title here")
                alertDialog.setMessage("Notifying user about API error")
                alertDialog.create().show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {
        //Update progress from here
    }
}
```

Call it from `Activity/Fragment` by passing **context** and *"your API URL"* :

```
TestApiCall(context).execute("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
```

Comment: where should l put those code ? in `onPreExecute` ? and what about alertdialog to inform user ?

Comment: Both of solutions are related to `doInBackground()`. You can display alert to user inside `onPostExecute` method conditionally.

Comment: he dosent work with alertdialog . When l tried to puted alert dialog in onPostExecute method conditionally l get error Type mismatch. `Required: Boolean Found: String?`   ! could you please to rewrite answer with alertdialog  ?