# Not using the @Override annotation when implementing an abstract method

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How come in the first code block of [this Runnable implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921759/6733153) there is no `@Override` annotation on `run()`? - `run()` is an abstract method:

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Compare this to my Android `onCheckedChanged` function which is also an abstract method:

```
currentlocation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object: RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checkedId: Int) {

    }

})
```

which has to have the `override` modifier (note: that's kotlin code but same principles apply).

How come the 2nd the 2nd code block needs to have the override keyword but the first doesn't?

Comment: "that's kotlin code but same principles apply" false

Answer (score 0):

That is because the language designers decided it like that. Kotlin requires explicit override modifiers while Java does not.

See [Overriding Methods in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods)