# Unknown cause of java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, mysql, ip, runtimeexception

When I tried to start my app which checks something with the database I have encountered irrational error. My app threw an java.lang.RuntimeException with the line: `OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();`

My code is:

```
 String result = "";
        String connstr = "http://myip:8080/androidlogin.php";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(connstr);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);

Log.d("TAG", "1");
            OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
            Log.d("TAG", "2");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ops,"UTF-8"));
            Log.d("TAG", "3");
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id,"UTF-8");
            Log.d("TAG", "4");
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            ops.close();

            InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String line ="";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            reader.close();
            ips.close();
            http.disconnect();
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = e.getMessage();
        }


        return result;
```

And my error looks like this:

```
2020-03-13 08:01:07.460 10633-10633/com.hu.jam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hu.jam, PID: 10633
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hu.jam/com.hu.jam.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The most interesting part is that between Log 1 and error there are three interesting messages on the logcat:

```
2020-03-13 08:01:07.442 10633-10633/com.hu.jam D/TAG: 1
2020-03-13 08:01:07.444 10633-10633/com.hu.jam I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-03-13 08:01:07.444 10633-10633/com.hu.jam I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
2020-03-13 08:01:07.451 10633-10633/com.hu.jam D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-03-13 08:01:07.460 10633-10633/com.hu.jam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Here is a php script:

```
<?php
$db = "database1";
$user = $_POST["user"];
$host = "localhost";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, "root", "", $db);
if($conn){
    echo "connected....!";
    $q= "select * from article where a_title='$user'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo"login successfull...!";
    }else {
        echo"login failed....!";
    }

}else{
    echo"connection failed....!";
}


?>
```

What is the problem with my code? Everything seems to be alright with it, yet it does not work...

Comment: Run that code in another thread.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer with code shown because that says little

Answer (score 0):

To work with network requests, it is recommended to run the code in a separate thread [How to run a Runnable thread in Android at defined intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921514/how-to-run-a-runnable-thread-in-android-at-defined-intervals)

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      //Put your network code here
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: can you post my code with these changes done? I'm a beginner so I don't really know what to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new `Runnable`. Remember, it needs to provide a mechanism for you to get the result once complete. Also, I strongly urge you to take advantage of the [`try-with-Resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of explicitly closing. Something like,

```
public class MyLoginRunnable implements Runnable {
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private String connstr;
    private String id;

    public MyLoginRunnable(String connstr, String id) {
        this.connstr = connstr;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(connstr);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoInput(true);
            http.setDoOutput(true);

            try (OutputStream ops = http.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( //
                            new OutputStreamWriter(ops, "UTF-8"))) {
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") //
                        + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8");
                writer.write(data);
            }

            try (InputStream ips = http.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( //
                            new InputStreamReader(ips, "ISO-8859-1"))) {
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
            http.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            sb.append(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
String connstr = "http://myip:8080/androidlogin.php";
MyLoginRunnable mlr = new MyLoginRunnable(connstr, "");
Thread t = new Thread(mlr);
t.start();
try {
    t.join(); // <-- this is for your simple example, in real code you don't want to pause
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String result = mlr.getResult();
```

Comment: Well I used your code and when I Logged.d the result it gave me "Connection refused"

Comment: @PozeraczSloikow Sounds like the server isn't working correctly at `http://myip:8080/androidlogin.php`

Comment: Well everything seems to be alright with androidlogin.php but I've posted it anyways for you by editing my question. BTW script is running on XAMPP.

Comment: Can you answer?

Comment: No. "Connection refused" has a pretty clear meaning. I can't help further, because I can't reproduce your environment. You need to make sure your connection string is correct. But again, connection refused means the **other** side refused the connection.

Comment: By the other you mean the server not the app?

Answer (score 0):

The exceptiin is because you are running a Network task which is supposed to be a background task, on the main UI thread. Use `AsyncTask` for Networking or IO tasks. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask